# Selecting a random record with WHERE conditions in cases of multiple matches

Tags: sql

I want to select records based on three conditions, let's say my query looks like this.

`SELECT id FROM table WHERE (postcode = 'A1C5E3' AND age = 4 AND gender = 12) OR (postcode = 'B0V1A0' AND age = 5 AND gender = 13) OR ...`

There might be more than one person, for example, in the postal code 'A1C5E3' with age = 4 and gender = 12 and this could be true for every set of conditions. Is there a way I can select only 1 id per (postal code, age, gender) if multiple matches are found? The one id could be randomly chosen.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregation:

```
SELECT MIN(id)
FROM table
WHERE (postcode = 'A1C5E3' AND age = 4 AND gender = 12) OR
      (postcode = 'B0V1A0' AND age = 5 AND gender = 13) OR ...
GROUP BY postcode
```